# How do I get the date range of the current org-agenda view in elisp?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm trying to get `org-agenda` to behave a bit more like a paper day planner, and have it only show deadlines on the day that they're due, rather than carrying them forward when they're overdue. So far, I've created a custom `org-agenda` view as follows:

```
(defun org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-not-today ()
  (ignore-errors
    (let ((subtree-end (save-excursion (org-end-of-subtree t)))
          (deadline-day
            (time-to-days (org-time-string-to-time (org-entry-get nil "DEADLINE"))))
          (now (time-to-days (current-time))))
      (and deadline-day
           (not (= deadline-day now))
        subtree-end))))

(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("b" agenda "Today's Deadlines"
    ((org-agenda-span 'day)
     (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-not-today))
     (org-agenda-entry-types '(:deadline))
     (org-agenda-overriding-header "Today's Deadlines")))))
```

However, this only shows the agenda entries for *today*. What I would like to do is pass into `org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-not-today` the date range of the current agenda view, and have it exclude subtrees whose deadline lies outside of that range.

Is it possible to do that with elisp? I've looked at the org manual for custom agenda views, but I haven't been able to find out get the date range for the current agenda view.

Comment: Try replacing `now` with `org-starting-day` in `(not (= deadline-day now))`. `org-starting-day` is defined in the agenda buffer. So, whether it works depends on which buffer is active when the command is executed.

Comment: Oh, it looks like `org-starting-day` is what I need, along with `org-agenda-span`. Could you please put your comment in as an answer, so I can accept it?